# MySQL data from database align horizontally

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

Im creating a basic website that will show 10 different tv programmes.
I have the 10 different programmes stored in the database. Im able to retriev the 10 programmes but they all appear in a column.
I was wondering if theres a way to have then appear 5 in a row?
I have tried basic CSS but i cant seem to get it working

Here is the code i have so far:

```
<?php
$results = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM programmes ORDER BY ProgrammeName ASC");
if ($results) { 
     while($obj = $results->fetch_object())
    {
        echo '<br>';
        echo '<div class="tvProgs">'; 
        echo '<form method="post" id = "books" action="cart_update.php">';
        echo '<div class="progImage"><img src="images/'.$obj->Image.'"></div>';
        echo '<div class="progTitle"><h3>'.$obj->ProgrammeName.'</h3>';
        echo '</form>';
        echo '</div>';
    }
}
?>
```

I was wondering if theres a way to achive that i want or will i have to try something else?

anything will help.

Thanks!

Comment: don't use divs, then. those are basically like `<p>` paragraphs... either make them inline-blocks, or use `<span>` instead. plus, even then you'll still have the `<br>`, enforcing line breaks.

Comment: Also, all your forms will have the same html id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to put them in a table:

```
<?php
$results = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM programmes ORDER BY ProgrammeName ASC");
if ($results) { 
     $i=0;
     echo '<table><tr>';
     while($obj = $results->fetch_object())
    {
        echo '<td>';
        echo '<div class="tvProgs">'; 
        echo '<form method="post" id = "books" action="cart_update.php">';
        echo '<div class="progImage"><img src="images/'.$obj->Image.'"></div>';
        echo '<div class="progTitle"><h3>'.$obj->ProgrammeName.'</h3>';
        echo '</form>';
        echo '</div>';
        echo '</td>';
        $i++; 
        if ($i == 5) {
          echo '</tr><tr>';
        }
    }
     echo '</tr></table>';
}
?>
```

Comment: This makes it `appear 5 in a row` like OP asked?

Comment: Thanks that seems to have worked but all 10 are in one row.

Comment: Oh sorry, I was focusing on the row vs. column requirement and did not pay attention to the 5 in a row requirement. Check the updated answer.

Comment: I think your update will produce 6 per row. `++$i` should work though.

Comment: You checked it while I was editing it. check it now. Or your change of 5 to 4 works :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can start from:

```
$i=0;
echo '<br>';
while($obj = $results->fetch_object())
{

    echo '<div class="tvProgs">'; 
    echo '<form method="post" id = "books" action="cart_update.php">';
    echo '<div class="progImage"><img src="images/'.$obj->Image.'"></div>';
    echo '<div class="progTitle"><h3>'.$obj->ProgrammeName.'</h3>';
    echo '</form>';
    echo '</div>';
    if (($i++) == 5) { echo '<br>'; $i=0; }
}
```

**UPDATE** CSS

```
.tvProgs {
    float:left;
    width:200px;
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: That didnt really do much. Everything is still in one big column.

Comment: Won't this put a `<br>` after 6 records?

Comment: Thats what i thought but for some reason on my screen its still just one big column.. @Alex I havent done any css for .tvProgs yet

Comment: Almost, `if (++$i == 5) { echo '<br>'; $i=0; }` should do the trick. I highly recommend [this article](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php)

Comment: @Tman by the way using a good css  you don't need that code fix at all. ;-) That is how responsiveness is realized in our days.

Answer (score 0):

This will put them in a table 5 in each row just like you asked for.

```
<?php
$results = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM programmes ORDER BY ProgrammeName ASC");
if ($results) {
    $i = 0;
    echo '<table>';
     while($obj = $results->fetch_object())
    {
        if ($i == 0) {
            echo '<tr>';
        }
        echo '<td>';
        echo '<div class="tvProgs">'; 
        echo '<form method="post" id = "books" action="cart_update.php">';
        echo '<div class="progImage"><img src="images/'.$obj->Image.'"></div>';
        echo '<div class="progTitle"><h3>'.$obj->ProgrammeName.'</h3>';
        echo '</form>';
        echo '</div>';
        echo '</tr>';

        $i++;

        if ($i == 5) {
            echo '</tr>';
            $i = 0;
        }
    }
    if ($i != 0) {
        echo '</tr>';
    }
    echo '</table>';
}
?>
```