# Trying to get MySQL results to display horizontally

Tags: php, html, css, mysql, mysqli

I'm creating a webpage that lists ten characters in a game based on their experience levels and displays them with a picture associated each character. My code works, but the output is in a column when I'd like it to be in a row. I did see where something very similar had been asked here: [MySQL data from database align horizontally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33376954/mysql-data-from-database-align-horizontally) and I tried to follow that example but either ended up with errors or the faces didn't appear. I'm a hobbyist, I'm just doing this for friends, so my knowledge is pretty basic.

Relevant code:

```
<table border="3" width="90%">
<tr>
<th width="25%">XP</th>
<td>
<?php 
$resultgood = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Life WHERE goodxp > 0 ORDER BY goodxp DESC LIMIT 10");
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultgood))
    {
    $face = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT face FROM Description WHERE charname='$row[charname]'");
    $row = mysqli_fetch_row($face);
    $face = $row[0];
    $name = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT charname FROM Life WHERE charname='$row[charname]'");
    $row = mysqli_fetch_row($name);
    $name = $row[0];
    echo "<left>";
    echo "<table border='1'>";
    echo "<tr><td>";
    echo "<img src='pictures/$face' alt='$name' border='2'>";
    echo "</td></tr>";
    echo "</table>";
    echo "<br>";
    }
?>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Anyone got any suggestions? Thanks!

---

So after following Bombelman's suggestion below, I got it to work. In case anyone else runs into this problem, here is the working code:

```
<tr>
<th width="25%">Goody Two Shoes</th>
<td><?php 
echo "<table border='1'><tr>";
echo "<left>";
$resultgood = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Life WHERE goodxp > 0 ORDER BY goodxp DESC LIMIT 10");
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultgood))
    {
    $face = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT face FROM Description WHERE charname='$row[charname]'");
    $row = mysqli_fetch_row($face);
    $face = $row[0];
    $name = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT charname FROM Life WHERE charname='$row[charname]'");
    $row = mysqli_fetch_row($name);
    $name = $row[0];
    echo "<td>";
    echo "<img src='pictures/$face' alt='$name' border='2'>";
    echo "</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "</table>";
?></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: you could probably do a join here not a nested query.

Comment: The situation is really two independent problems. 1. Getting data from MySQL using PHP. 2. Showing data in your desired format. I'm sure you can get answers to both of these pretty easily.

Comment: Yes. Have a read about JOINs. There's tons of superfluous code here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

place the "table" and "row" tag out of the loop, and have the results in between the "td" tags looped only.

Looking at your script, you have several tables.

Make sure only the < td > and < /td > tags are within the while-loop.
The output should be similar to my example.

Hope it helps !

```html
<table style="width:100%">

  <tr>
    <td>Character 1</td>
    <td>Character 2</td>
    <td>Character 3</td>
    <td>Character 4</td>
    <td>Character 5</td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the sql queries makes me think you ought to be able to do a basic join upon the two tables rather than having nested queries within a loop. The generation of the html table should be fairly straightforward - iterate through the recordset results for rows in the table and iterate through the fields returned by the query for individual cells within the table row.

```
$sql='select l.*, d.face from `life` l
    join `description` d on d.`charname`=l.`charname`
    where l.`goodxp` > 0 
    order by l.`goodxp` desc 
    limit 10';

$res=$con->query( $sql );

/* fetch the column names into an array */
$fields=array();
array_walk( $res->fetch_fields(),function( $item, $key, $fields ){
    $fields[]=$item->name;
},&$fields );


$html=array();

$html[]='<table>';
/* add field names as column headers */
$html[]='<tr>';
foreach( $fields as $field )$html[]='<th>'.$field.'</th>';
$html[]='</tr>';

/* 
    iterate through recordset, 
    add new row for every record 
    but table cell for every 
    field in record
*/
while( $rs=$res->fetch_object() ){
    $html[]='<tr>';

    foreach( $fields as $field ){/* show image or text */
        $data = $field=='face' ? "<img src='pictures/{$rs->$field}' />" : $rs->$field;
        $html[]='<td>'.$data.'</td>';
    }

    $html[]='</tr>';
}
$html[]='</table>';

/* render table */
echo implode( PHP_EOL, $html );
```

Depending upon the version of PHP you may get nagged at when using the `array_walk` function and passing the third argument by reference. If that is the case then change

```
$fields=array();
array_walk( $res->fetch_fields(),function( $item, $key, $fields ){
    $fields[]=$item->name;
},&$fields );
```

for

```
$fields=array();
array_walk( $res->fetch_fields(),function( $item, $key ){
    global $fields;
    $fields[]=$item->name;
} );
```